# How do I retrieve the 'id' of an entry/row from an 'item' in the entry/row?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

Building an app using React Native (for iOS) using AWS Amplify

I want to do something seemingly so simple, but i am a bit lost as to how to do it: I have a table with user information already in it. Here's the Schema:

```
type Users @model {
  id: ID!
  userName: String
  firstname: String
  weblink: String
  email: String
  mobileNum: String
 .
 .
 .
}


//**Here's my current Query.js**
export const getUsers = `query GetUsers($id: ID!) {
  getUsers(id: $id) {
    id
    userName
    firstname
    weblink
    email
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
`;
```

This table is populated in DynamoDB when i check my AWS console. What i need is to be able to get the id from the table using the userName (not vice versa). The id is generated when i createUser() and it's used throughout my app to get all my user's information. However when a user signs in on a new phone, this id isn't available anymore. So when they sign in via Cognito, i do know the userName and all i need to do is retrieve this id. Because there's only one unique **userName**, it should only return one **id**

Here's what i'm thinking so far: use a GSI (global secondary index). So change my schema to:

```
type Users @model
    @key(
       name: "ByUsername"
       fields: ["userName"]
       queryField: "getIdFromUserName"
    )  
{
  id: ID!
  userName: String
  firstname: String
  weblink: String
  email: String
  mobileNum: String
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Then call in my app:

```
const data = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getIdFromUserName, { userName }));
```

5 questions:

1) Is there a simpler way than GSI?

2) Is that how you add the GSI? Or is it more robust to do it in the AWS console?

3) What should my **Query.js** then look like?

4) Do i need to make a custom resolver, or is this sufficient?

5) Am i missing anything else, or can i just

```
amplify push  ?

//11/04/2020
//Resolver

## [Start] Prepare DynamoDB PutItem Request. **
$util.qr($context.args.input.put("createdAt", $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.input.createdAt, $util.time.nowISO8601())))
$util.qr($context.args.input.put("updatedAt", $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.input.updatedAt, $util.time.nowISO8601())))
$util.qr($context.args.input.put("__typename", "Users"))
#set( $condition = {
  "expression": "attribute_not_exists(#id)",
  "expressionNames": {
      "#id": "id"
  }
} )
#if( $context.args.condition )
  #set( $condition.expressionValues = {} )
  #set( $conditionFilterExpressions = $util.parseJson($util.transform.toDynamoDBConditionExpression($context.args.condition)) )
  $util.qr($condition.put("expression", "($condition.expression) AND $conditionFilterExpressions.expression"))
  $util.qr($condition.expressionNames.putAll($conditionFilterExpressions.expressionNames))
  $util.qr($condition.expressionValues.putAll($conditionFilterExpressions.expressionValues))
#end
#if( $condition.expressionValues && $condition.expressionValues.size() == 0 )
  #set( $condition = {
  "expression": $condition.expression,
  "expressionNames": $condition.expressionNames
} )
#end
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "PutItem",
  "key": #if( $modelObjectKey ) $util.toJson($modelObjectKey) #else {
  "id":   $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.defaultIfNullOrBlank($ctx.args.input.id, $util.autoId()))
} #end,
  "attributeValues": $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($context.args.input),
  "condition": $util.toJson($condition)
}
## [End] Prepare DynamoDB PutItem Request. **
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You dont need to create GSI (global secondary index).

2) You can update your createUser resolver, instead of using `$util.autoId()` you can pass `$ctx.args.input.userName` as id

Comment: Hi Muhammad. I still use '$ctx.args.input.id' for most of my operations. However i only really need to use 'userName' once or twice. I just don't want to disrupt what's already there with the 'id' (maybe thats why i thought GSI). Can i share my resolver with you to figure out how this can be achieved? Thanks

Comment: I've added my createUser resolver (Amplify automatically generated it). So i use the 'id' 95% of the time to get data from my Users table in DynamoDB. And 5%, i need to use the userName JUST to get the corresponding 'id'. Wouldn't it be safer to create a custom resolver in the Resolvers folder?